# Administrator Cannot Uninstall A Normal User's Application

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, uninstallation

**Scenario:**

Normal User A (no admin rights) installs the application for current user (himself) only. That works fine.

Now, an Administrator should be able to uninstall that same application Normal User A installed. However, the app is not showing in the Add/Remove programs for the administrator. It is only showing for Normal User A.

In my MSI app, I have an option to install either for the current user or for all users.

I have tried setting `ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT` to `0` but that still doesn't make the program to show in the Admin's ARP.

My problem is similar to [this](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?179614-Program-not-showing-up-in-Add-Remove-Programs-for-all-users), but I cannot set `ALLUSERS` to `1` as Normal User A won't have the sufficient rights to proceed installation. (Yes, I have tried doing that.)

I am using InstallShield 2013 Premier, and I am a newbie in using this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a Windows Installer application is installed for a single user, it is registered under that user's HKCU registry hive. When populating the ARP, Windows looks in both HKLM and the current HKCU registry hives. However the administrator and the non-administrator do not share the same HKCU so the single user install's registration is not available to the administrator. So as you've presented them, your requirements (per-user install, uninstall by a different user) are in conflict with each other.

Comment: See Rule #30: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windows_installer_team/archive/2006/05/24/605835.aspx

Comment: Not exactly the answer our customers will want to hear but it is the correct one nonetheless.